# Android WebView back button go back twice

Tags: android, webview

Hello i have  a fragment with webview here it is:

```
public class ListaCanali extends Fragment {

TextView textView;
WebView webView;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_canali,container,false);

    //Titolo Fragment
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Ultimi Film Pubblicati");

    //FindViewById
    webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //Impostazioni WebView
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://testoetraduzione.org");
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());

    //Tasto Indietro
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Why when i press back button the webview go back twice! Please write me a right code! of course i rate the best

Comment: Look @ Implementing back navigation for webview's @ http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: you are not handling the key event i.e up or down that is why onkey() is getting called twice!

Comment: so can you write me the code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `setOnKeyListener`on `WebView`, override `onKeyDown` method of the activity. You have to handle well fragment lifecycle, if not it can bring to a crash.

Get the instance of the fragment in your activity:

```
// Fragment f = instance of your fragment
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && f != null && f.canGoBack()) {
        f.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And add these methods in your fragment:

```
public boolean canGoBack() {
    return webView != null &&webView.canGoBack();
}

public void goBack() {
    if(webView != null) {
       webView.goBack();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: 'webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean canGoBack() {
                return webView != null &&webView.canGoBack();
            }

            public void goBack() {
                if(webView != null) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }
            }
        });' show me errore in View.OnKeyListener

Comment: @SimoneVarletta I said to put onKeyDown in activity that holds this fragment, not in the fragment. And read better my answer, there isn't any method I used in my snippet. You have to remove setOnKeyListener in fragment and put those two methods (canGoBack() and goBack()). Then in activity you have to get instance of your fragment and override onKeyDown method

Comment: @SimoneVarletta I can't explain it better. I'll try in italian:
Allora, dovrei parlare inglese ma così facciamo prima. Il metodo onKeyDown() va nell'activity da cui fai il replace del fragment, i metodi canGoBack() e goBack() vanno nel fragment, sono due metodi pubblici. Nel mio snippet c'è scritto tutto ciò che c'è da sapere, non capisco perchè continui a mettere foto con snippet diversi dal mio. Dovresti ipoteticamente fare solo copia-incolla. L'unica cosa che devi fare te è ottenere l'istanza del fragment nell'activity che lo tiene

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't even need a keylistener on the back button to go back, because it already is configured to do so! That's why it would go back twice : once by the nature of the button, once because of your actionlistener

Comment: just delete the portion `webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });`